# Append to file1 on differences of specific column between two files

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I would like to compare the two files, and only print this line and append it to "source.txt":

```
01.02.70 08h00,4.4.4.4,443
```

Here are my files:

> **source.txt**
>
> ```
> DATETIME,IPSOURCE,PORT
> 01.01.70 08h00,0.0.0.0,443
> 01.01.70 08h00,2.2.2.2,443
> ```
>
> **events.txt**
>
> ```
> DATETIME,IPSOURCE,PORT
> 01.02.70 09h00,0.0.0.0,443
> 01.02.70 09h00,2.2.2.2,443
> 01.02.70 08h00,4.4.4.4,443
> ```

I don't care about the DATETIME field in the comparison, I only want to add the new IP that appears in the log file "events.txt" to "source.txt" (addresses 0.0.0.0 and 2.2.2.2 appear in the two files).

So I want to use

```
grep -vxFf source.txt events.txt
```

without taking the first field into account, I look only for differences in the IPSOURCE field (second column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` when you need field based comparison

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ip[$2]=$0; next} $2 in ip{delete ip[$2]} END{for(k in ip) print ip[k]}' events.txt source.txt
01.02.70 08h00,4.4.4.4,443
```

- `-F,` set `,` as input field separator
- `NR==FNR{ip[$2]=$0; next}` use second field as key and save entire line in associative array. This block of code will execute only for first file input (i.e events.txt)
- `$2 in ip{delete ip[$2]}` when second file (i.e source.txt) is processing, delete elements in `ip` array if second field was already present
- `END{for(k in ip) print ip[k]}` after all input is processed, print lines remaining in `ip` array

Or, change the order of input files and print lines from events.txt if second field was not present in source.txt

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ip[$2]; next} !($2 in ip)' source.txt events.txt
01.02.70 08h00,4.4.4.4,443
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{arr[$2]=$0;next} !($2 in arr)' source event #>> source
```

If you want have appended difference line based on second column with comma separated fields, just Uncomment `>> source` in above command.

NO, if you want to compare based on IP:Port part. then you can use as following.

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{arr[$2FS$3]=$0;next} !($2FS$3 in arr)' source event #>> source
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your conditions:

> - append it to "source.txt"
> - I only want to add the **new** IP that appears in the log file
>     "events.txt" to "source.txt"

---

Here's a complete solution based on combination of GNU **sed**, **cut** and **grep**:

```
sed -i "\$ a $(cut -d, -f2 source.txt | grep -vf - events.txt)" source.txt
```

---

The resulting `source.txt` file contents:

```
DATETIME,IPSOURCE,PORT 
01.01.70 08h00,0.0.0.0,443 
01.01.70 08h00,2.2.2.2,443
01.02.70 08h00,4.4.4.4,443
```